# What are the advantages of using `functionGlobalContext` in node-red?

Tags: node.js, node-red

While I was trying out nodered I came across `functionGlobalContext` in settings object.

Nodered Document says

> it is a collection of objects to attach to the global function context,
>   *and we can access that **collection** inside our custom nodes*

My concern is, I can also use `global` object of **nodejs** to accomplish the same, then what is the difference?

Comment: Where does it actually say that? I can't seem to find the documentation for this.

Comment: you can find here https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/configuration#node-configuration

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not use the  native nodejs `global` object, because this is not exposed in the Node-RED function node sandbox (which as the name implies is what the context was initially for). It has been replaced with access to the objects declared in the `functionGlobalContext` object.

While you can user the Node-RED context variables from within your custom nodes, you should really be using variable's locally scoped to your own node for things that are related to the internal working of the node, you should only be using the context object if you need to use the state in things like the built in change or switch nodes.

Comment: I've tried using nodejs global object from anywhere in the program. for eg: I've created a key in global object in `main.js` and that I can access in my custom node function.

Comment: Ño! I'm talking about in the shipped core Function Node. Edit the original question to explain what problem you are actually trying to solve here.

Comment: Finally, I understood, the confusion was that I only looked at the coding part and thinking from a backend perspective. as you said- `as the name implies` - I found that in UI of node-red when clicked to a custom node there is an option called "Context Data". so any object I link to `functionGlobalContext` appears here. Thanks for the help.